# How to get list of Long from list of object

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have a Person object having following attributes-

```
private Long personId;
private String personName;

I want to get List<Long> from List<Person>
```

I want to avoid looping thru the object list. Please suggest if any other way is there.

Comment: Please mention what u have tried...and ur input and output...this seems to be a very vague question

Comment: Mithun..ask with actual input and expected output and objective for quick answers

Comment: Why do you want to avoid looping? Is this a matter of style or a matter of performance?

Comment: Mithun..please accept any workable one of the answer so that it would be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: There is still another way which would fullfill the requirement of not looping. But this one is more complex than the others and should only be done if speed is an issue. (E.g. for large lists.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to avoid looping through the list; either you can do it manually with a `for` loop, or you can have a library do it for you (such as with Google Guava Functions or Java 8 streams). The simplest way if you're not already using Guava is simply this:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList(people.size());
for(Person p : people)
    id.add(p.getPersonId());
```

Comment: Ideed there is a way. And it makes very much sense if you have to deal with large lists. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party unit to finish the goal: com.google.common.collect.Collections2.transform(collection, Function), although it is also loop the collection internal.
PS: A demo of how to use the method is like:

```
List<Long> personIds = Collection2.transform(persons, new Function<Person,Long>(){
       @Override
       public Long apply(@Nullable Person person) {
           return person.getPersonId();
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

List ids = (List) CollectionUtils.collect(objectList,                                     new BeanToPropertyValueTransformer("personId"));

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without using third party modules and **without iterating** (and without writing too much code):

Just write a Wrapper for your person list which accesses the Ids:

```
static class PersonIdList extends AbstractList<Long> {

    private final List<Person> wrapped;

    public PersonIdList( List<Person> wrapped ){
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Long get( int index ) {
        return wrapped.get( index ).personId;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return wrapped.size();
    }

}
```

which can be used this way:

```
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person( 1L, "Foo" ),
            new Person( 2L, "Bar" ),
            new Person( 3L, "Joshua" ) );

    PersonIdList personIds = new PersonIdList( persons );

    for( Long id : personIds ){

        System.out.println( id );
    }
```

This solution works best of cause with random access lists (e.g. ArrayList) and not so good
with sequential lists (e.g. LinkedList).

If you need it for linked lists and performance is an issue (large linked list, large database results) you could extend AbstractSequentialList and its Iterator or directly implement List and Iterator.

Both would be more code than this one but I think with this one you should get the idea.